# How to use UIScrollview with paging enabled and the touch events of following and previous images

Tags: ios, ipad, uiscrollview, pagination

I'm creating an iPad Application where I have created a UIScrollview which has paging enabled. I have number of images and each images are subviews  of the view and view is a subview of scrollview. There are multiple view.Views are of different sizes. I'm able to get the touch event of the image which is at the centre of scrollview. But I also want to get touch events of following and previous image within the scrollview.

Is it possible to do same thing without enabling paging.Because if paging is disabled then i can get touch events easily. But I want same paging effect

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit more?

Comment: what following and previous image ?

Comment: I mean the image next and previous to the centre image

Answer (score 0):

Dont use UIImageViews if you want touch events to be registered. Use UIButtons and set the images for each button. You can customise the button be extending it or use the hit states to control the images displayed on touch.

Comment: I cant add images of lager size on buttons

Comment: that makes no sense, buttons and images both ca be as big as you want

Comment: I'm getting touch event on scrollview.But I want to get touch event for image

Comment: The app which I'm trying to make I cant add button in place of view

Comment: UIButton is an extension of UIView.

Answer (score 0):

check contentSize of your scrollView. Maybe the width is not enough for 3 images.